# Keyboard-navigation not properly working in multilevel boostrap dropdown-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

At w3schools.com I found this example, just to keep it simple:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

It works fine, when I navigate using a keyboard. But when I add some further level - I cant reach next level:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <!-- next level -->
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1-2<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-2A</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-2B</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-2C</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In my project, I have tried to write a jquery-keyboard handler for dropdown, but the sub-level, still wont toggle.

Comment: you can try to add `tabindex` attribute

Comment: I have tried - but without success. But thanks anyway